SQL Query Fails with Certain Dataset but Works After Deleting Other Records
I'm facing an issue with a leaderboard query in my GraphQL API. The query is designed to fetch the highest WPM for each user, and in case of a tie, it should use accuracy and createdAt to determine the rank.
Here's the query I’m using:
SELECT 
    "test"."id" AS "test_id", 
    "test"."creatorId" AS "test_creatorId", 
    "test"."time" AS "test_time", 
    "test"."accuracy" AS "test_accuracy", 
    "test"."wpm" AS "test_wpm", 
    "test"."rawWpm" AS "test_rawWpm", 
    "test"."chars" AS "test_chars", 
    "test"."createdAt" AS "test_createdAt", 
    "test"."testTaken" AS "test_testTaken", 
    "creator"."id" AS "creator_id", 
    "creator"."uid" AS "creator_uid", 
    "creator"."username" AS "creator_username", 
    "creator"."email" AS "creator_email", 
    "creator"."createdAt" AS "creator_createdAt", 
    "creator"."updatedAt" AS "creator_updatedAt"
FROM 
    "test" "test"
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT 
        "t"."creatorId" AS "creatorId", 
        MAX("t"."wpm") AS "max_wpm"
    FROM 
        "test" "t"
    WHERE 
        "t"."time" = $1
    GROUP BY 
        "t"."creatorId"
) "max_tests" 
    ON max_tests."max_wpm" = "test"."wpm" 
    AND max_tests."creatorId" = "test"."creatorId"
LEFT JOIN 
    "user" "creator" 
    ON "creator"."uid" = "test"."creatorId"
WHERE 
    "test"."time" = $1 
    AND "test"."accuracy" = (
        SELECT 
            MAX("t2"."accuracy") 
        FROM 
            "test" "t2"
        WHERE 
            "t2"."time" = $1 
            AND "t2"."wpm" = "test"."wpm"
            AND "t2"."creatorId" = "test"."creatorId"
    )
    AND "test"."createdAt" = (
        SELECT 
            MIN("t3"."createdAt")
        FROM 
            "test" "t3"
        WHERE 
            "t3"."creatorId" = "test"."creatorId"
            AND "t3"."wpm" = "test"."wpm"
            AND "t3"."accuracy" = "test"."accuracy"
    )
ORDER BY 
    "test"."wpm" DESC, 
    "test"."accuracy" DESC, 
    "test"."createdAt" ASC;


This is the leaderboard resolver:
@Query(() => LeaderBoard)
  async leaderboard(
    @Ctx() ctx: Context,
    @Arg('uid') uid: string,
    @Arg('time') time: number
  ): Promise<LeaderBoard> {
    const qb = ctx.em
      .createQueryBuilder(Test, 'test')
      .innerJoin(
        (subQuery) =>
          subQuery
            .select('MAX(t.wpm)', 'max_wpm')
            .addSelect('t.creatorId', 'creatorId')
            .from(Test, 't')
            .where('t.time = :time', { time: time })
            .groupBy('t.creatorId'),
        'max_tests',
        'max_tests.max_wpm = test.wpm AND max_tests."creatorId" = test."creatorId"'
      )
      .where('test.time = :time', { time: time })
      .andWhere((qb) => {
        const subQuery = qb
          .subQuery()
          .select('MAX(t2.accuracy)')
          .from(Test, 't2')
          .where('t2.time = :time')
          .andWhere('t2.wpm = test.wpm')
          .andWhere('t2.creatorId = test.creatorId')
          .setParameter('time', time)
          .getQuery();
        return `test.accuracy = (${subQuery})`;
      })
      .andWhere((qb) => {
        const subQuery = qb
          .subQuery()
          .select('MIN(t3.createdAt)')
          .from(Test, 't3')
          .where('t3.time = :time')
          .where('t3.creatorId = test.creatorId')
          .andWhere('t3.wpm = test.wpm')
          .andWhere('t3.accuracy = test.accuracy')
          .setParameter('time', time)
          .getQuery();
        return `test."createdAt" = (${subQuery})`;
      })
      .leftJoinAndSelect('test.creator', 'creator')
      .orderBy('test.wpm', 'DESC')
      .addOrderBy('test.accuracy', 'DESC')
      .addOrderBy('test.createdAt', 'ASC');

    const tests = await qb.getMany();
    let userRank: number = -1;
    let userName: string = '';
    let userWpm: number = 0;
    let userAccuracy: number = 0;
    let userRawWpm: number = 0;
    let userTime: number = 0;
    let testTaken: string = '';

    let leaderBoard = [];

    let prevWpm = Infinity;
    let prevAccuracy = 0;
    let rank = 0;

    for (let i = 0; i < tests.length; i++) {
      const { wpm, accuracy } = tests[i];

      if (wpm < prevWpm || (wpm === prevWpm && accuracy > prevAccuracy)) {
        rank = i + 1;
        prevWpm = wpm;
        prevAccuracy = accuracy;
      } else {
        rank += 1;
      }

      leaderBoard.push({
        rank,
        user: tests[i].creator.username,
        wpm: wpm,
        rawWpm: tests[i].rawWpm,
        time: tests[i].time,
        accuracy: accuracy,
        testTaken: tests[i].testTaken,
      });

      if (tests[i].creatorId === uid) {
        userRank = rank;
        userName = tests[i].creator.username;
        userWpm = tests[i].wpm;
        userRawWpm = tests[i].rawWpm;
        userTime = tests[i].time;
        userAccuracy = tests[i].accuracy;
        testTaken = tests[i].testTaken;
      }
    }
    // change slice end no to whatever number of tests have to be shown
    leaderBoard = leaderBoard.slice(0, 50);

    return {
      leaderBoard,
      user: {
        rank: userRank,
        user: userName,
        wpm: userWpm,
        rawWpm: userRawWpm,
        time: userTime,
        accuracy: userAccuracy,
        testTaken: testTaken,
      },
    };
  }

This is the test entity:
@ObjectType()
@Entity()
export class Test extends BaseEntity {
  @Field()
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id!: number;

  @Field()
  @Column()
  creatorId: string;

  @ManyToOne(() => User, (user) => user.tests)
  @JoinColumn({ name: 'creatorId', referencedColumnName: 'uid' })
  creator: User;

  @Field()
  @Column()
  time: number;

  @Field(() => Float)
  @Column('double precision')
  accuracy: number;

  @Field()
  @Column()
  wpm: number;

  @Field()
  @Column()
  rawWpm: number;

  @Field()
  @Column()
  chars: string;

  @Field(() => String)
  @CreateDateColumn()
  createdAt: Date;

  @Field()
  @Column()
  testTaken: string;
}


The problem occurs when I run the query with my full dataset. Specifically, the query only returns one record in the leaderboard for time = 60, even though there are multiple records for different users. Interestingly, when I deleted all other records (keeping only the tests with time = 60), the query worked correctly and returned the expected results.
This leads me to believe the issue is related to how the data interacts with the query. My goal is to fetch only the highest WPM test for each user, with ties broken by accuracy and createdAt.
Why would the query work with a smaller dataset (with only tests for time = 60) but fail when other records (for example tests with time = 15,45,30,120) are present? Is there something wrong with how I'm using JOIN or ORDER BY that’s causing this behavior?
You can access the site
I have opened an issue so incase you have a solution you can open a PR here: Github

Without a sample reproducible data there is not much we can do to help. For this specific case what would be a sample of the data when you only have the rows for time=60 and a sample of the data with the time=60 and different times (no need to add many, just enough that would make your problem reproduce).

@JorgeCampos I have uploaded the sample data entirely since I am not exactly sure at which exact record the issue is arising from, in this case test for uid2 for time = 60 doesn't appear in the result for leaderboard query even though it should have since there are only two users

There are 15 fields in your select and 9 on your dataset, how are we able to know which is which? Help us to help you! Maybe use gpt to generate a fiddle script for it.

@JorgeCampos I have updated the question with the sample data, https://github.com/Rohith-JN/type-backend/blob/main/database-sample.csv

You didn't filter the values in your t3 scalar subquery by specific time "t3"."time"=$1

@Fred damn how did I miss this

@Fred I guess you can add it as an answer :)
